# Modify $READLINE_LINE and $READLINE_POINT values inside bash script

Tags: bash, autocomplete

[I already asked this question on stackoveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178632/modify-readline-line-and-readline-point-values-inside-bash-script), but received no answer and very few views. I thought I would post here as there should be more bash users and someone might have already stumbled upon this problem. According to [SO Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266053/is-it-ok-to-cross-post-a-question-between-non-stack-exchange-and-stack-exchange), it should be ok to do so as long as I link to the cross-website post. Tell me if I'm wrong though, and I'll just delete this question.

---

I tried to implement some features of `ksh` path autocompletion in `bash` by binding a custom script to a key. In order to do that, my script read the informations from `bind` variables `$READLINE_LINE` and `$READLINE_POINT` and attempts to update those values. While I can read the line buffer without issues, I can't seem to modify those variables and update the current line.

Quotting bind mand page, this should work though :

> When shell-command is executed, the shell sets the READLINE_LINE variable to the contents of the readline line buffer and the READLINE_POINT variable to the current location of the insertion point. If the executed command changes the value of READLINE_LINE or READLINE_POINT, those new values will be reflected in the editing state

I bound my scipt with `bind -x '"\t":autocomplete.sh'`, and did something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
#autocomplete.sh
echo $READLINE_LINE $READLINE_POINT   #I can read the current line values
EXPANSION=($(magical_autocomplete $READLINE_LINE))
#we store the desired value for the line in ${EXPANSION[0]}
[[ ${#EXPANSION[@]} -gt 1 ]] && echo ${EXPANSION[@]:1} #we echo the match if there are more than 1

READLINE_LINE=${EXPANSION[0]}
READLINE_POINT=${#READLINE_LINE}
#echo READLINE_LINE READLINE_POINT echoes the correct values found by magical_autocomplete
#however the current line & the current point is not updated
```

As I am echo-ing some informations, I can't just redirect the ouptut of my script to `$READLINE_LINE` in the `bind` call. Why can I read from the variables but not write into them ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just by the same reason why this won’t work:

```
$ export a=1
$ bash -c 'echo $a; let a++'
1
$ echo $a
1
```

Environment variables are *heritable*, not shareable. Since `autocomplete.sh` is executed as a new child process, it can read all parent’s variables, but can‘t push new values back.

To modify `READLINE_LINE` and `READLINE_POINT` you have to execute your autocomplete in the same process – `source` and functions will help you.

```
# autocomplete.sh
# should be sourced from ~/.bashrc or something

autocomplete() {
    echo $READLINE_LINE $READLINE_POINT
    EXPANSION=($(magical_autocomplete $READLINE_LINE))
    #we store the desired value for the line in ${EXPANSION[0]}
    [[ ${#EXPANSION[@]} -gt 1 ]] && echo ${EXPANSION[@]:1}

    READLINE_LINE=${EXPANSION[0]}
    READLINE_POINT=${#READLINE_LINE}
}
```

Binding:

```
if [[ -s "$HOME/.bashrc.d/autocomplete.sh" ]]; then
    source "$HOME/.bashrc.d/autocomplete.sh" 
    bind -x '"\t" : autocomplete'
fi
```

Comment: Note: does not work for bash 3.x (RIP Mac users).

Comment: @dlsso, sorry, I didn't get the question.  I could not find any `" "` neither in Aserre's question nor in what I wrote in answer.

Comment: My mistake. I meant to ask: What would the syntax be if you wanted to use a variable instead of `"\t"`? I tried `"$char"`, `"${char}"`, `"$(char)"` but none seem to work.

Comment: @dlsso, either `"$char"` or `"${char}"`.  `"$(char)"` means substituting result of calling `char` (whatever is is: function, executable, alias, etc).