# Change in bash prompt depending on whether first character is a space

Tags: bash, prompt, readline

Right now every command which starts with a space character gets ignored by bash history (`HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth` in `~/.bashrc`).
I would like to have a better visual cue when I press space as the first character in the prompt input field.

So is there a method of adding such a thing in the bash prompt?
For example, you would color a part of the prompt when it notices that you press space *as the first character of the input field* (because obviously reacting to other space characters in the input field would be silly).

Comment: Probably not: bash writes its prompt *before* you start typing, and does not update the prompt.

Comment: I guess some `bind` magic can take you there. Adding readline tag.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Readline 7.0 is able to change the prompt based on which mode your readline vi-mode is in, so this statement is not true. But, well, a general-purpose RL command for changing a prompt still doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

So, admittedly, this is a little hackish but I think it will accomplish your end goal (even if it's not in the way you wanted).  In your `.bashrc` (or anywhere else that gets sourced on login) add something similar to the following.

```
check_space() {
    if [[ "$READLINE_LINE" == " " ]]; then
        echo "This command will not be recorded in .bash_history!!"
    fi
    READLINE_LINE="$READLINE_LINE "
    READLINE_POINT=$(($READLINE_POINT+1))
}
bind -x '" ": check_space'
```

Every time the space bar is pressed it will call the `check_space` function to see whether it should print out a warning or not.

Thanks to help from Jeff [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251155/using-bind-to-read-the-current-command-line/251164#251164)  who got help from Dmitry [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149192/modify-readline-line-and-readline-point-values-inside-bash-script/149196#149196)

EDIT FOR dlsso:

To use an arbitrary char instead of space:

```
check_char() {
    char=$1;
    if [[ "$READLINE_LINE" == "$char" ]]; then
        echo "This command will not be recorded in .bash_history!!"
    fi
    READLINE_LINE="$READLINE_LINE$char"
    READLINE_POINT=$(($READLINE_POINT+${#char}))
}
for char in {a..z}; do
    bind -x '"$char": check_char $char'
done
```

Comment: Note: does not work for bash 3.x (RIP Mac users).

Comment: What would the syntax be if you wanted to use a variable instead of `" "`? I tried `"$char"`, `"${char}"`, `"$(char)"` but none seem to work.

Comment: How and where are you trying to set the variable?  `$char` and `${char}` should both work if set appropriately.

Comment: `for char in {a..z}` so perhaps it's not the same as a normal variable. `echo $char` works as expected in that case though, so I expected the binding to work as well.

Comment: @dlsso Check my edit

Comment: Thanks, looks like this has the same problem as my attempt though. `check_char()` doesn't get hit. My `$BASH_VERSION` is `4.3.0(1)-release`