# Using bind to read the current command line

Tags: bash, readline

I'm using `bind -x` to execute a script whenever a certain key sequence is pressed.

For example I have a script at `/usr/local/bin/foo` with the contents

```
#!/bin/bash
echo foo
```

If I run `bind -x '"  ": /usr/local/bin/foo'` then every time I press the space bar twice it echos "foo".  So far so good.

What I want to be able to do is access (and ideally modify) the current command that's being entered.  If I type `some really long command` (there are two spaces at the end) my script gets executed but how can it see that I've already entered `some really long command` and change it to `some other long command`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149196/117549), I think you would have to make your script into a sourced bash function, have it modify READLINE_LINE (and READLINE_POINT according to the new length / desired cursor point), and then `bind -x '"  " : that-function-name'`.

Just to clarify; if you only want to modify *some* commands with double-space, do something like:

```
autocomplete() {
if [ "$READLINE_LINE" = "some really long command" ]
then
    READLINE_LINE="some other long command"
    READLINE_POINT=23
fi
}

bind -x '"  " : autocomplete'
```

Comment: Thanks for prompting me to learn a bit more about bind & readline!

Comment: No problem.  I think we both did some good learning today :)  This was in an effort to answer the question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238891/change-in-bash-prompt-depending-on-whether-first-character-is-a-space/251177#251177

Comment: Note: does not work for bash 3.x (RIP Mac users).

Comment: What would the syntax be if you wanted to use a variable instead of `" "`? I tried `"$char"`, `"${char}"`, `"$(char)"` but none seem to work.

Comment: Because of the outer strong (single) quotes